# Codename One: hide title (area) but not status bar space (iOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, codenameone, toolbar, title

I have an app for iOS and Android.
The status bar is not hidden.
My main form has no title and no back command and no other commands in the toolbar.
(All my other forms do have a title and back command.)
I want to hide the title because I need the space.
I found that on iOS devices an empty title ("") does the job.
But on Android devices it doesn't; the form content is not shown on the first call to form.show().
It is shown if we pause and resume the app.
It appears that the Android implementation needs a non-empty title, even if it is hidden.

So my implementation is:

```
// we use Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true)
public class MainForm extends Form {
    public MainForm() {
        super(""); // hides the title area but not the status bar space on iOS
        if (android()) {
            setTitle(" "); // Android needs non-empty title
            getToolbar().hideToolbar(); // hides the title area; don't use on iOS, it removes the status bar space too
        }
        ...
```

Is this a correct implementation? I could not find any documentation on this.

**Edit** after the comments below:

I tried the suggestion getToolbar().setUIID("Container") on ios too. This removes the Toolbar top padding so only the status bar is left. However, at least in the simulator, the bottom of the status bar is then no longer aligned with the bottom of the iPhone X notch (it is above it). So I assume the padding is necessary, just as on forms which have a title (and back command). So I arrive at the following implementation:

```
// hide title area
super(""); // hides title area on ios (not status bar space and toolbar padding)
if (android()) {
    // hide title area (=toolbar) explicitly
    // use *either* this:
    getToolbar().hideToolbar();        // on ios this also hides the status bar space
    // *or* this:
    getToolbar().setUIID("Container"); // on ios this also hides the Toolbar top padding
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such requirement on Android. An empty title should work fine across platform. See if you get an exception in the device console when navigating with an empty title.

Comment: Thanks. I tried again and it works on Android too (both "" and null work). I have been unable to reproduce the problem; I didn't get an exception but the form content didn't show (unless paused & resumed). Anyway, it is good to know that an empty title is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Actually no, it doesn't work on Android without getToolbar().hideToolbar(). If you just set an empty title the title area still occupies space. So on iOS an empty title is sufficient but on Android you need to hide the toolbar (the title can be empty though).

Comment: Try `getToolbar().setUIID("Container")`

Comment: Yes, that is another way to achieve the same on Android. On iOS it works differently. I will edit my question.